# issue installing hunspell on the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, zsh, hunspell

I installed hunspell because it's required for lint on atom. Though when I run `hunspell` on the command line I get: `Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named "en_US".`

When I run `hunspell -D` I get:

```
SEARCH PATH:
.::/usr/share/hunspell:/usr/share/myspell:/usr/share/myspell/dicts:/Library/Spelling:/Users/jessiematias/.openoffice.org/3/user/wordbook:/Users/jessiematias/.openoffice.org2/user/wordbook:/Users/jessiematias/.openoffice.org2.0/user/wordbook:/Users/jessiematias/Library/Spelling:/opt/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:  /opt/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo
AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
```

I was under the impression my Mac OS Catalina already had an English dictionary installed. Do I have to manually install another dictionary? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [README,](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell#usage) you need to download dictionaries separately, for example:

```
wget -O en_US.aff  https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.aff?id=a4473e06b56bfe35187e302754f6baaa8d75e54f
wget -O en_US.dic https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.dic?id=a4473e06b56bfe35187e302754f6baaa8d75e54f
```